# Does CDI reuse proxies for RequestScoped?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, threadpool, cdi, proxies

If I create a bean annotated with `@RequestScoped` I expect that it will instantiate a new proxy instance with each new request.

From the other hand each request is associated with its own thread.

**My question is:** will CDI reuse previously created proxy object of my bean/service if the new request reuses previously created thread from a pool?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, it's important to understand that **client proxy object != bean instance** (or contextual instance if we want to follow the spec wording). For `@RequestScoped` a new bean instance is always created for each request. However, `@RequestScoped` is a normal scope, which means that a client proxy is injected (and this proxy delegates to the bean instance).

Now back to your question to client proxy object - the strategy is implementation-specific. The spec states that a container might instantiate one client proxy object per bean and share it between multiple injection points. But it's not required (see also [this documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#client_proxies)). Reference implementation (Weld, WildFly, GlassFish, etc.) **DOES share** client proxy objects. But again, we're speaking about client proxies, not bean instances.

WRT thread association - request context is associated with one thread but when the request ends the context is destroyed (incl. all bean instances) and the thread is dissociated.

Comment: So the answer is: no?

Comment: Nope, the answer is -"yes, **Weld** may reuse the proxy objects".

Comment: I mean, it is implied from what Martin said and I can fully second his answer, that's the way it is in Weld. But then again, it's internal thingie. CDI spec doesn't mandate how this should work.